# CakePHP. app/Console/cake: Permission denied for root user

Tags: php, bash, shell, cakephp, root

I am using CakePHP 2.4.7 and I'm trying to execute CakePHP shell on remote host.

I'm connecting to server as root and then executing `$ [path_to_my_foler]/app/Console/cake`

The output is: `-bash: [path_to_my_foler]/app/Console/cake: Permission denied`

How could it be? How to fix it?

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l [path_to_my_foler]/app/Console/cake`?

Comment: Marek, the output is: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1383 Apr  4 18:25 [path_to_my_folder]/app/Console/cake`

Comment: Make sure the file is executable (-x). Also, always run the console relative from your APP dir. So do "cd app" first, then "Console/cake".

Comment: I typed `$ [path_to_my_foler]/app` and then `Console/cake`. Got `Permission denied`. Then i tryed to type `Console/cake -x` and also got `Permission denied`.

Comment: I'll expand @mark comment, first `cd` to `[path_to_my_foler]/app`, next use `chmod +x Console/cake` to make it executable, and then `Console/cake`

Comment: Thanks for the correction of the typo :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Did you get this solve? I think this could do the trick. (Running the command from your `app` directory

```
 chmod +x Console/cake
```

Comment: Thank you boss! You saved my day.　:)

Comment: Hey I'm trying to do so, but it said chmod: changing permissions of ‘Console/cake’: Operation not permitted. I'm using CakePHP 2.8 on Amazon. Any suggestion?

Comment: you may not have the permissions to do so, try running the command with sudo if you can.

Answer (score 8):

In CakePHP Version 3 and above this is the right command.

```
chmod +x bin/cake
```

This is CakePHP documentation for reference.

> **Console**
>
> The cake executable has been moved from the app/Console directory to
> the bin directory within the application skeleton. You can now invoke
> CakePHP’s console with bin/cake.

[Documentation link](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#console)